# Define unique columns on ManyToMany in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to add unique columns on a pivot table created via a `ManyToMany` association.

I found this [page of the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint) explaining how to generate a database unique constraint on some columns with this example:

```php
 /**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ecommerce_products",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="search_idx", columns={"name", "email"})})
 */
class ECommerceProduct
{
}
```

But this only works if I create the pivot table via a third entity and, in my case, I created the pivot table using a [ManyToMany](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany) relation (in the same fashion as [this code](https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916)).

Is there a way to add unique columns on pivot table while still using `ManyToMany` or do I need to rely on a third entity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [`@Table`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-table) annotation proposes a `uniqueConstraints` option, [`@JoinTable`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-jointable) does not. Thus, if you want to add a unique constraint on your association table, you will have to actually create another entity explicitly.

That being said, the default join table should not need anything more than the default configuration set up by Doctrine. Currently, when adding a `ManyToMany` association, the join table is composed of two fields and a composite primary key relying on both fields is created.

If your association table only contains the two basic fields referring to both sides of your association (which is necessarily the case if you use `@ManyToMany`), the composite primary key should be all you need.

---

Here is the generated SQL for the basic example where a `User` has a `ManyToMany` association with `Group` ([from this section of the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_groups (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    group_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, group_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE users_groups ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id);
ALTER TABLE users_groups ADD FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES Group(id);
```

As you can see, everything is properly set up with a composite primary key which will ensure that there can't be duplicate entries for the couple `(user_id, group_id)`.

Comment: I never realized that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is another alternative, Alan!

If you need a Zero to Zero relationship, the only alternative is defining the unique constraint per each pk in the agregated table, to make doctrine figuring out about zero to zero relationship.

The problem is that Doctrine's people hadn't considered zero to zero relationships, so the only alternative for this is manytomany relationship with one unique constraint per pk.

If you have doubts about final-state of your doctrine implementation of your E-R model, I strongly recommend mysql-workbench-schema-exporter. With this php tool, you can easily export your mysql workbench E-R schema to a Doctrine's working classes schema, so you would be able to easily explore all your alternatives ;-)

Hope this helps